# I can't find a way to select items from a list, each made of three text fields

Tags: java, android, listview, onitemclicklistener, onitemclick

I have looked at tens of examples and tutorials, and I have tried to repeat the same steps, but it is not working.

In my activity, I have four onClickListeners that work perfectly fine and are related to four buttons on the top part of my layout. The problem arises when, in addition, I try to set an onItemClickListener for the items of the ListView in the bottom part of the same layout. Each item of this ListView is made of three textViews, and I have written a custom adapter for them. They show up perfectly, but when I click on them nothing happens (the onItemClick instructions are never reached).

This is the layout, the problem is with the "ingredients_list_view" towards the end:
(by the way, the very last item, @android:id/list", is there only because otherwise I get a compile error in my activity, I haven't yet figured out why - otherwise I don't need it, and it is not supposed to show or do anything at all)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/label_recipe_name"
        android:layout_gravity="top"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:id="@+id/editTextTitle"
        android:layout_gravity="top"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/label_servings"
        android:layout_gravity="top"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:id="@+id/editTextServings"
        android:layout_gravity="top"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/label_cake_size"
        android:layout_gravity="top"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:id="@+id/editTextSize"
        android:layout_gravity="top"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/btnEditDelete"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/button_edit"
                android:id="@+id/btnEdit"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/button_delete"
                android:id="@+id/btnDelete"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:id="@+id/btnSaveCancel"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/button_save"
                android:id="@+id/btnSave"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/button_cancel"
                android:id="@+id/btnCancel"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ingredients_list_view"
        android:divider="#48C"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:id="@android:id/list"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the layout for each item of the listView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ingredient_list_item"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/quantity_list_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/unit_list_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

... and  these are the relevant sections of the main activity:

```
public class Recipe extends ListActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static final String TABLE = "Recipes";

    public static final String KEY_ID = "recipeID";
    public static final String KEY_title = "title";
    public static final String KEY_servings = "servings";
    public static final String KEY_size = "size";

    public int recipeID;
    public String title;
    public String servings;
    public String size;

    Button btnEdit, btnDelete, btnSave, btnCancel;
    LinearLayout btnEditDelete, btnSaveCancel;
    EditText editTextTitle;
    EditText editTextServings;
    EditText editTextSize;

    int _Recipe_Id;
    int editMode;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe_view);
        redraw();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
// These work perfectly fine (except for the last one)
        RecipeDBOps repo = new RecipeDBOps(this);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> recipeList = repo.getRecipeList(); // so far not used
        if (view == findViewById(R.id.btnDelete)) {
            MixDBOps.delete(_Recipe_Id);
            RecipeDBOps.delete(_Recipe_Id);
            finish();
        }
        else if (view == findViewById(R.id.btnEdit)) { // Changes the fields to "editable" and switches button
            setEditMode();
        }
        else if (view == findViewById(R.id.btnCancel)) {
            finish();
        }
        else if (view == findViewById(R.id.btnSave)){
            Recipe recipe = RecipeDBOps.getRecipeById(_Recipe_Id);
            recipe.title = editTextTitle.getText().toString();
            recipe.servings = editTextServings.getText().toString();
            recipe.size = editTextSize.getText().toString();
            RecipeDBOps.update (recipe);
            finish();
        }
        else if (view == findViewById(R.id.ingredients_list_view)){
            System.out.println("OK2"); // Tried, but doesn't work
        }
    }

    public void setWeight (LinearLayout ll, LinearLayout.LayoutParams visibility){...}

    public void setReadOnlyMode(){...}

    public void setEditMode(){...}

    public void redraw(){
        editTextTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTitle);
        editTextServings = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextServings);
        editTextSize = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSize);
        btnEdit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);
        btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        btnEditDelete = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.btnEditDelete);
        btnSaveCancel = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.btnSaveCancel);

        setReadOnlyMode();

        //
        // Populate recipe fields
        //
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        _Recipe_Id = intent.getIntExtra("recipe_ID", 0);
        editMode = intent.getIntExtra("editMode", 0);
        RecipeDBOps repo = new RecipeDBOps(this);
        Recipe recipe;
        recipe = repo.getRecipeById(_Recipe_Id);

        if (recipe.title != null) {
            editTextTitle.setText(recipe.title);
            editTextServings.setText(recipe.servings);
            editTextSize.setText(recipe.size);
        }

        //
        // Populate recipe and ingredient fields
        //
        ArrayList<Entry> arrayOfEntries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        EntryAdapter adapter = new EntryAdapter(this, arrayOfEntries);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ingredients_list_view);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // This is the part that does not work
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ListView clickedObj = (ListView) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            // Once I am able to activate this onItemClick I will write the rest of the code to deal with clickdObj 
            System.out.println("OK1");
        }});
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        HashMap<String, String> h;
        MixDBOps repoMix = new MixDBOps(this); // repo represents the DB
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> entryList = repoMix.getMixById(_Recipe_Id); // recipeList is the output of the SQL query
        Entry[] ent = new Entry[entryList.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < entryList.size(); i++) {
            h = entryList.get(i);
            ent[i] = new Entry();
            ent[i].recipe_name = recipe.title;
            ent[i].ingredient_name = h.get("ingredient_name"); // temporarily replaced by spinner
            ent[i].quantity= Integer.parseInt(h.get("quantity"));
            ent[i].unit_name= h.get("unit_name");
            adapter.add(ent[i]);
        }

        btnEdit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);
        btnEdit.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(this);

        if (editMode == 1){
            setEditMode();
        }
    }
}
```

Is anybody able to help me?

Comment: About the item with `@android:id/list`: this happens because your Activity inherits from [ListActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity). Since you provide your own layout, you can have your Activity inherit directly from AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 1):

add two attribute in each edit text of item of list view

```
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
```

Comment: Just tried, but they don't seem to make any difference

Comment: i think this problem happen because when you click in list view , list view don't recognition you'r click. please check when you click in item of list view do you see any effect in list view that show you click in item. for example when you click in item , item show an small animation .

Comment: In fact, there is no sign at all that my click is recognised

Comment: in you'r question you say "Each item of this ListView is made of three textViews" but in you'r code you add three Edit text.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have tried with both. In fact, these are supposed to be EditText that are programmatically enabled or disable (i.e., you click on "edit" and the texts become editable). Still, my idea is that I click on something on the same line (the three text items belonging to the same ListView entry) and the "onclick" is triggered, but it doesn't happen

Comment: when you click in item of list view in fact you focus on edit text and list view don't recognation you'r click . also you can use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18475098/click-on-list-item-of-a-listview-doesnt-respond)

Comment: Eventually I've been able to make it work. My original code was OK-ish, but the "focusable" and "clickable" have made the difference