# onItemClick() event not fired with HorizontalScrollView in android

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview, android-chips

I'm using  [ChipView](https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips) in android.

I've added `HorizontalScrollView` to [chips_recipient_dropdown_item.xml](https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips/blob/master/library/src/main/res/layout/chips_recipient_dropdown_item.xml) file.
but now the `onItemClick` event is not fired of the class `RecipientEditTextView.java`

**RecipientEditTextView.java**

[https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/android/ex/chips/RecipientEditTextView.java#:~:text=%40Override-,public%20void%20onItemClick(AdapterView%3C%3F%3E%20parent%2C%20View%20view%2C%20int%20position%2C%20long%20id)%20%7B,-if%20(position](https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/android/ex/chips/RecipientEditTextView.java#:%7E:text=%40Override-,public%20void%20onItemClick(AdapterView%3C%3F%3E%20parent%2C%20View%20view%2C%20int%20position%2C%20long%20id)%20%7B,-if%20(position)

```
   /**
     * When an item in the suggestions list has been clicked, create a chip from the
     * contact information of the selected item.
     */
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (position < 0) {
            return;
        }
        submitItemAtPosition(position);

        if (itemSelectedListener != null) {
            itemSelectedListener.onItemSelected();
        }
    }
```

**chips_recipient_dropdown_item.xml (With HorizontalScrollView):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="56dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@android:id/icon"
        style="@style/ChipIconStyle"
        android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_contact_picture" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbarSize="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@android:id/title"
                style="@style/ChipTitleStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:alpha=".87"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@android:id/text1"
                    style="@style/ChipSubtitleStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:alpha=".54"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@android:id/text2"
                    style="@style/ChipSubtitleStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:alpha=".54"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I've added `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`to the topmost root layout ([ListView with horizontalScrollView OnItemClick not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049086/listview-with-horizontalscrollview-onitemclick-not-working#:%7E:text=android%3AdescendantFocusability%3D%22blocksDescendants%22)) , so it's working only on `ImageView` but not working with `LinearLayout inside HorizontolScrollView`.

I also tried `android:clickable="false" android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` to HorizontalScrollView but nothing works.

Can anyone please suggest to me How can I solve this?

Thanks in Advance.